# Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I got an error on my browser window "Cannot read property 'string' of undefined" when i import module (import { Button } from 'react-lightning-design-system'), even i am not using this module.

[image]

```js
//package.json

{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-lightning-design-system": "^2.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Comment: Could you please share some code with us? Just by sending your error message it not helpful.

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to incompatible module verions. Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: I guess it is because `react-props-types` is removed from react `v16`. Now you have to manually install it. Here it is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it's a `PropTypes` issue I'm guessing it's a React v15 vs React v16 issue (i.e. you're using one version of React, but that module requires the other version). Check the dependencies.

Probably gonna need some more info then just an out of context error message though

Answer (score 0):

Using [react-codemon](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod), run on your project directory

`jscodeshift -t react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js myapp/`

This will resolve updating proptypes for your source code and any node modules.

Re-installing node modules will require running the command again it seems.